# Ansible task fails, but same command works manually

Tags: ansible, tomcat8

I'm running command in Ansible task, as you can clearly see its configuring tomcat-native:

```
- name: configure tomcat apr native library
  become_user: root
  become: true
  shell: "./configure --with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto"
    chdir: "/opt/tomcat/bin/tomcat-native-1.2.23-src/native"
  register: configureoutput
```

Which gives me the following output:

```
TASK [../../../../roles/ghi.install_apr_tomcat : configure tomcat apr native library] ***
changed: [aps01]
changed: [aps02]
TASK [../../../../roles/ghi.install_apr_tomcat : debug] ************************
ok: [aps01] => {
    "configureoutput": {
        "changed": true,
        "cmd": "./configure --with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto",
        "delta": "0:00:00.712919",
        "end": "2023-02-17 21:14:13.094244",
        "failed": false,
        "rc": 0,
        "start": "2023-02-17 21:14:12.381325",
        "stderr": "./configure: line 3139: cd: /bin/apr-1-config//usr/lib64/apr-1/build: Not a directory\ncp: cannot stat '/apr_rules.mk': No such file or directory",
        "stderr_lines": [
            "./configure: line 3139: cd: /bin/apr-1-config//usr/lib64/apr-1/build: Not a directory",
            "cp: cannot stat '/apr_rules.mk': No such file or directory"
        ],
        "stdout": "checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu\nchecking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu\nchecking target system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu\nchecking for a BSD-compatible install... /bin/install -c\nchecking for working mkdir -p... yes\nTomcat Native Version: 1.2.36\nchecking for chosen layout... tcnative\nchecking for APR... yes\nconfigure: APR 1.7.2 detected.\n  setting CC to \"gcc\"\n  setting CPP to \"gcc -E\"\nchecking JAVA_HOME... /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto\n  adding \"-I/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/include\" to TCNATIVE_PRIV_INCLUDES\nchecking for JDK os include directory...  linux\n  adding \"-I/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/include/linux\" to TCNATIVE_PRIV_INCLUDES\nchecking for gcc... gcc\nchecking whether the C compiler works... yes\nchecking for C compiler default output file name... a.out\nchecking for suffix of executables... \nchecking whether we are cross compiling... no\nchecking for suffix of object files... o\nchecking whether the compiler supports GNU C... yes\nchecking whether gcc accepts -g... yes\nchecking for gcc option to enable C11 features... none needed\nchecking for OpenSSL library... using openssl from /usr/local/ssl/lib and /usr/local/ssl/include\nchecking OpenSSL library version >= 1.0.2... ok\nchecking for OpenSSL DSA support... no\n  adding \"-I/usr/local/ssl/include\" to TCNATIVE_PRIV_INCLUDES\n  setting TCNATIVE_LDFLAGS to \"-L/usr/local/ssl/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/ssl/lib -lssl -lcrypto\"\n  adding \"-DHAVE_OPENSSL\" to CFLAGS\n  setting TCNATIVE_LIBS to \"\"\n  setting TCNATIVE_LIBS to \"  -L/bin/apr-1-config//usr/lib64  -lapr-1  -lpthread -ldl\"\n  adding \"-DTCNATIVE_LINUX\" to CFLAGS\nchecking for apr_pollset_wakeup in -lapr-1... no\nconfigure: creating ./config.status\nconfig.status: creating Makefile\nconfig.status: executing default commands",
        "stdout_lines": [
            "checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu",
            "checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu",
            "checking target system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu",
            "checking for a BSD-compatible install... /bin/install -c",
            "checking for working mkdir -p... yes",
            "Tomcat Native Version: 1.2.36",
            "checking for chosen layout... tcnative",
            "checking for APR... yes",
            "configure: APR 1.7.2 detected.",
            "  setting CC to \"gcc\"",
            "  setting CPP to \"gcc -E\"",
            "checking JAVA_HOME... /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto",
            "  adding \"-I/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/include\" to TCNATIVE_PRIV_INCLUDES",
            "checking for JDK os include directory...  linux",
            "  adding \"-I/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/include/linux\" to TCNATIVE_PRIV_INCLUDES",
            "checking for gcc... gcc",
            "checking whether the C compiler works... yes",
            "checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out",
            "checking for suffix of executables... ",
            "checking whether we are cross compiling... no",
            "checking for suffix of object files... o",
            "checking whether the compiler supports GNU C... yes",
            "checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes",
            "checking for gcc option to enable C11 features... none needed",
            "checking for OpenSSL library... using openssl from /usr/local/ssl/lib and /usr/local/ssl/include",
            "checking OpenSSL library version >= 1.0.2... ok",
            "checking for OpenSSL DSA support... no",
            "  adding \"-I/usr/local/ssl/include\" to TCNATIVE_PRIV_INCLUDES",
            "  setting TCNATIVE_LDFLAGS to \"-L/usr/local/ssl/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/ssl/lib -lssl -lcrypto\"",
            "  adding \"-DHAVE_OPENSSL\" to CFLAGS",
            "  setting TCNATIVE_LIBS to \"\"",
            "  setting TCNATIVE_LIBS to \"  -L/bin/apr-1-config//usr/lib64  -lapr-1  -lpthread -ldl\"",
            "  adding \"-DTCNATIVE_LINUX\" to CFLAGS",
            "checking for apr_pollset_wakeup in -lapr-1... no",
            "configure: creating ./config.status",
            "config.status: creating Makefile",
            "config.status: executing default commands"
        ]
    }
}
```

But the same command completes successfully when I run it manually (Makefile is created only when configure was successful):

```
[root@ip-############ native]# ./configure --with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking for working mkdir -p... yes
Tomcat Native Version: 1.2.36
checking for chosen layout... tcnative
checking for APR... yes
configure: APR 1.7.2 detected.
  setting CC to "gcc"
  setting CPP to "gcc -E"
checking JAVA_HOME... /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto
  adding "-I/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/include" to TCNATIVE_PRIV_INCLUDES
checking for JDK os include directory...  linux
  adding "-I/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/include/linux" to TCNATIVE_PRIV_INCLUDES
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether the compiler supports GNU C... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to enable C11 features... none needed
checking for OpenSSL library... using openssl from /usr/local/ssl/lib and /usr/local/ssl/include
checking OpenSSL library version >= 1.0.2... ok
checking for OpenSSL DSA support... no
  adding "-I/usr/local/ssl/include" to TCNATIVE_PRIV_INCLUDES
  setting TCNATIVE_LDFLAGS to "-L/usr/local/ssl/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/ssl/lib -lssl -lcrypto"
  adding "-DHAVE_OPENSSL" to CFLAGS
  setting TCNATIVE_LIBS to ""
  setting TCNATIVE_LIBS to " /usr/lib64/libapr-1.la  -lpthread -ldl"
  adding "-DTCNATIVE_LINUX" to CFLAGS
checking for apr_pollset_wakeup in -lapr-1... yes
  adding "-DHAVE_POLLSET_WAKEUP" to CFLAGS
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: executing default commands
[root@ip-############ native]# ls -la
total 336
drwxrwxr-x 7 tomcat tomcat   4096 Feb 17 21:47 .
drwxrwxr-x 8 tomcat tomcat    304 Feb  8 15:52 ..
drwxrwxr-x 3 tomcat tomcat    257 Feb 17 21:47 build
-rwxrwxr-x 1 tomcat tomcat   2946 Feb  8 15:52 buildconf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tomcat tomcat   1098 Feb  8 15:52 build.conf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tomcat tomcat   6191 Feb  8 15:52 BUILDING
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tomcat tomcat   3587 Feb  8 15:52 build-outputs.mk
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tomcat tomcat   8769 Feb  8 15:52 config.layout
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root    10260 Feb 17 21:47 config.log
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root      146 Feb 17 21:47 config.nice
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root    26231 Feb 17 21:47 config.status
-rwxrwxr-x 1 tomcat tomcat 170805 Feb  8 15:52 configure
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tomcat tomcat   7269 Feb  8 15:52 configure.in
drwxrwxr-x 2 tomcat tomcat     78 Feb  8 15:52 include
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tomcat tomcat   6845 Feb  8 15:52 libtcnative.dsp
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tomcat tomcat   1214 Feb  8 15:52 libtcnative.dsw
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tomcat tomcat  17499 Feb  8 15:52 LICENSE.bin.win
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root     2766 Feb 17 21:47 Makefile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tomcat tomcat   2376 Feb  8 15:52 Makefile.in
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tomcat tomcat   5413 Feb  8 15:52 NMAKEmakefile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tomcat tomcat   9745 Feb  8 15:52 NMAKEmakefile.inc
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tomcat tomcat    695 Feb  8 15:52 NOTICE.bin.win
drwxrwxr-x 4 tomcat tomcat     31 Feb  8 15:52 os
drwxrwxr-x 2 tomcat tomcat   4096 Feb  8 15:52 src
drwxrwxr-x 4 tomcat tomcat     64 Feb  8 15:52 srclib
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tomcat tomcat   6833 Feb  8 15:52 tcnative.dsp
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tomcat tomcat   2833 Feb  8 15:52 tcnative.spec
```

And the most fun thing is: my task was working on February 10-th (merged into main branch), then somebody tried to deploy this code on February 15-th and it failed. Commit hash is the same, no MR/PR was merged into main branch.

Does anyone have detective skillzZz?

edit:
One more important thing to notice:
Ansible stderr says -
`"stderr": "./configure: line 3139: cd: /bin/apr-1-config//usr/lib64/apr-1/build: Not a directory\ncp: cannot stat '/apr_rules.mk': No such file or directory",`
if we look into that file, we'll see

```
[root@ip-172-24-8-48 ~]# sed -n 3139p /opt/tomcat/bin/tomcat-native-1.2.36-src/native/configure
      APR_BUILD_DIR="`cd $APR_BUILD_DIR && pwd`"
```

So, the root of the problem might be it. For some reason Ansible calculating value for APR_BUILD_DIR in a wrong way. I don't get it. It's official tars from Tomcat website and I'm installing them in a required way.

Comment: the output in your ansible task looks the same as the output when you run it manually so I am not sure I understand what the issue is

Comment: Well, stdout is the same, but ansible task also has stderr, which manual command doesn't have.

Comment: Ah sorry didnt see that.

Comment: Output are not the same, check closely. Ansible says `-L/bin/apr-1-config//usr/lib64  -lapr-1`, manually you'ld get `/usr/lib64/libapr-1.la `. The bsd install path also mismatches ... You're certain those outputs came from the same machine? Check the differences between `env` running in shell vs. ansible.

Comment: I'm 100 sure it's from the same machine. I've tried the playbook and when task failed first thing I tried - re-do failed command and it was successful.

Comment: You have a syntax problem (see my answer), but there is no error message?! [edit] the question and it [mre].

Comment: The error is `'/apr_rules.mk': No such file or directory`. [edit] the question and make it [mre]. In particular, find out why `/apr_rules.mk` is missing.

Comment: This question should be closed as *"Not about programming or software development"*. It's the subject of [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). Make it [mre] there. Focus on `'/apr_rules.mk': No such file or directory`.

Answer (score 2):

Q: ***"cannot stat '/apr_rules.mk': No such file or directory"***

A: The error is:

> "stderr": "./configure: line 3139: cd: /bin/apr-1-config//usr/lib64/apr-1/build: Not a directory\ncp: cannot stat '/apr_rules.mk': No such file or directory",

You should find out why `/apr_rules.mk` is missing.

---

[*chdir*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html#parameter-chdir) is not a [*keyword*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html#playbook-keywords)  it is parameter of the module *shell*. If you ran the task

```yaml
- name: configure tomcat apr native library
  become_user: root
  become: true
  shell: "./configure --with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto"
  chdir: "/opt/tomcat/bin/tomcat-native-1.2.23-src/native"
  register: configureoutput
```

you must have seen this error:

> ERROR! conflicting action statements: shell, chdir

The correct syntax is *chdir* nested as a parameter of *shell*

```yaml
- name: configure tomcat apr native library
  become_user: root
  become: true
  shell: "./configure --with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto"
    chdir: "/opt/tomcat/bin/tomcat-native-1.2.23-src/native"
  register: configureoutput
```

Comment: It is nested in my code, seems like I missed it when I was formatting my question:)